# Do I need iOS or Android device(s) to write applications using Visual Studio with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile-development

With the free Xamarian with Visual Studio does a Windows Developer using a Windows Machine have to buy Iphones, Ipads & Andoid devices to convert c# Windows into IOS or Android? When trying to create C# from withing Visual Studio / Xamarian it is asking me to pair a mac that I do not have. Is it mandatory to use physical devices rather than emulators? Thank You for this opportunity!

Comment: Removed the vs tag as this is agnostic for general mobile development.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an Android or iOS device for development, although obviously building apps without being able to test them on real devices is not ideal.

For iOS, you must have a Mac to act as a build host when using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you need a Mac at least.

The Android emulators is OK for any other OS.

For Windows Phone 8, you need a Windows 8+ PC.